What’s the best training set modality for a model that takes two random configurations as input and predicts which one is better?
I want to create a model that predicts which Spark configuration is better. What’s the best dataset for this? Is it better to compare different configurations of various Spark jobs one-on-one using combinatorics for pairwise comparison then training the models on that, or should I calculate the differences between each configuration (e.g., configuration 1 uses less memory than configuration 2 but uses more cores)? Is it logical to create a dataset like this?

To train a model, you'll need examples of configurations and how "good" they are. How do you define "better"? Which of the two example configurations you mention is the best? Is it meaningful to use a single number to say that a configuration with more cores but less memory is better or worse than a configuration with fewer cores but more memory? Is it meaningful to classify the goodness of a configuration without knowing what kind of task it will be used for?

@NuclearHoagie better is defined through resources consumption. The less resources consumed the better the configuration is. The goal is to ultimately optimize the resources that the spark jobs consume by tweaking different parameters like memory and number of cores and so on. Also, in Spark there are 4 types of workloads ( memory intensive/processing intensive/ Iterative/ I-O.) so by using 4 different benchmarks like wordcount terasort pagerank and naivebayes classifier I could generalize the different task types
